# Is this code that uses Streams wrong or should I submit a bug?

Tags: dart

The code I wrote may be kind of long for a question but, I want to see if there's a bug so I can submit it to dartbug.com . In case there's not a bug I would like to know what I did wrong.

The idea for the code is to sync a point's position with a grid (Square class and Grid class respectively).

Square.onPosChange is a Stream that sends the previous position.

When a square is added to the Grid (Grid.add), there's a subscription to onPosChange that what it does is change the location of the square in the Grid; first it removes it from the previous position (just assigns null), and then assigns it to the current position.

The test I have fails when it expects the previous position to be null. Now below is the code and notice the commented line where I think may be the problem.

Edit: Just in case, this is not an April Fools question :P

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main() {
  test('grid',(){
    Square s = new Square(3, 5);
    Grid g = new Grid(10,10);
    g.add(s);
    expect(g._cols[3].squares[5], s);//pass
    s.x = 6;
    expect(g._cols[6].squares[5], s);//pass
    expect(g._cols[3].squares[5], isNull);//fails

  });
}

class Grid{
  List<GridCol> _cols;
  int w, h;
  Grid(this.w, this.h){
    _cols = new List<GridCol>.filled(w, new GridCol(h));
  }
  add(Square square){
    if(!isOut(square)){
      //add square to grid
      _cols[square.x].squares[square.y] = square;
      //listen to onPosChanged event stream
      square.onPosChanged.listen((Point previousPos){
        //remove from previous position
        _cols[previousPos.x].squares[previousPos.y] = null;
        //if is not out of bounds, add in new position
        if(!isOut(square)){
          /*
           * Up until this point, (3,5) is null, as was set earlier.
           * (6,5) is also null since it was never set.
           * 
           * But after the following line, strangely,
           *  both (3,5) and (6,5) are set to the square.
           */
          _cols[square.x].squares[square.y] = square;

          print("(3,5): ${_cols[3].squares[5]}");//(3,5): (6,5)
          print("(6,5): ${_cols[6].squares[5]}");//(6,5): (6,5)
        }

      });
    }
  }

  isOut(Point p) => 
      p.x < 0 || p.y < 0 || p.x >= w || p.y >= h;
}

class GridCol{
  List<Square> squares;
  GridCol(int h): squares = new List<Square>(h);
}

class Square extends Point{
  int get x => super.x;
      set x (value){
        var prev = super.x;
        super.x = value;
        _sc.add(p(prev, y));
      }
  int get y => super.y;
      set y (value){
        var prev = super.y;
        super.y = value;
       _sc.add(p(x,prev));
      }

  StreamController<Point> _sc;
  Stream get onPosChanged => _sc.stream;
  Square(x, y)
  {
    super.x = x;
    super.y = y;
    _sc = new StreamController<Point>.broadcast();
  }
}

 class Point{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0; 
    Point([this.x, this.y]);
    String toString() => '($x,$y)';
}

p(x, y) => new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a hard one to track down, but here's your fix, and it is nothing to do with Streams.

The constructor for Grid looks like this:

```dart
Grid(this.w, this.h){ 
  _cols = new List<GridCol>.filled(w, new GridCol(h));
}
```

where you expect every element in `_cols` to be filled with a `new GridCol(h);`.  Actually what you get (and what the code actually says), is fill each element with the same instance of `GridCol`.   This can better be seen when re-written slightly as :

```dart
Grid(this.w, this.h){
  var gridCol = new GridCol(h);  // create a single instance of a GridCol
  _cols = new List<GridCol>.filled(w, gridCol); // add that instance to every element
}
```

This means that when you add your first square, every `GridCol` is the same, single instance, you end up with a grid that looks like this (where `-` is null and `S` is your square):

```
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
---S------
```

This happens right at the start of the `add` function, before any streams are involved, just after the comment: `//add square to grid`.

If you initialize each element in the grid using the following code, your tests pass.

```dart
Grid(this.w, this.h){
  _cols = new List<GridCol>(w); // create the list
  // fill each element with a different GridCol
  for (int i = 0; i < _cols.length; i++) {
   _cols[i] = new GridCol(h); // insert a new GridCol for every element.
  }
}
```